# NAudio как зациклить звук

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

Искал информацию в интернете, находил только кучу огромного кода, где ничего не понятно, и проблему это никак не решало. Как мне зациклить звук? В интернете я видел использование *LoopStream* но он у меня почему то не работает, пишет что не существует в текущем контексте. На данный момент я воспроизвожу звук так:

```
   WaveStream m1 = new WaveFileReader("sound/silence.wav");
   WaveOutEvent M_Silence = new WaveOutEvent();
   
   M_Silence.Init(m1);
   M_Silence.Play();
```

Comment: Первая ссылка гугла по запросу [c# naudio loop](https://www.markheath.net/post/looped-playback-in-net-with-naudio), пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал. На этом сайте я бал не раз. Мало что понял из него

Comment: Пробовали и не работает, или пробовали и не понял? Как по мне, там все очень просто, делаете обертку над `WaveStream`, который в конце ставит позицию на 0, что зациклит чтение потока.

Comment: Ну.. Ладно.. Попробую более детальнее всё изучить. Я думал есть способ попроще чем этот. Спасибо